# Tomcat 8: SSL session ID not available

Tags: ssl-certificate, tomcat8

I'm having a problem trying to migrate from Tomcat7 to Tomcat8. Things seems to work fine, but when I access my application it logs this Exception:

```
09-Nov-2016 13:23:09.192 WARNING [https-openssl-nio-9443-exec-3] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.populateSslRequestAttributes Exception getting SSL attributes
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: SSL session ID not available
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLEngine$OpenSSLSession.getId(OpenSSLEngine.java:1048)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESupport.getSessionId(JSSESupport.java:156)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.populateSslRequestAttributes(AbstractProcessor.java:619)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.action(AbstractProcessor.java:359)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.action(Request.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getAttribute(Request.java:900)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getAttribute(RequestFacade.java:282)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.propogateSecureSession(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:411)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.setupMessage(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:395)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:238)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:298)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:217)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:273)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:589)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My connector is defined this way:

```
<Connector port="9443"  URIEncoding="utf-8" protocol="HTTP/1.1"     
    scheme="https"  secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"     
    maxPostSize="-1"
    useAprConnector ="false"
    sslProtocol="TLSv1.2" clientAuth="want"         
    disableSessionTickets="true"
    keystoreFile="${catalina.home}/conf/keystore.jks" 
    keystorePass="..." 
    truststoreFile="${catalina.home}/conf/truststore.jks" 
    truststorePass="..." 
/>
```

Things works fine on Tomcat7, and also in tomcat8 the secure conection is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are hitting [Bug 59811 - TLS Session ID not available if session tickets are used](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59811).

I suspect that this is because in switching to Tomcat 8.5.x OpenSSL is used for TLS if it is available.

You have a couple of options:

- Add an explicit SSLHostConfig element and include `disableSessionTickets="true"` to disable session tickets
- Set `sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation"` on the Connector to use JSSE for TLS rather than OpenSSL

The second option is closest to what you had with Tomcat 7.

Comment: Is `disableSessionTickets="true"` safe?

Comment: Yes. The cost is an increase in server memory usage. How much will vary case by case. You'll have to test your environment to know what the figures are for you.